# Firestore get data once then update. looping of data Snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

The data keeps on looping. how can i make it read only once?

```
 onAddToCart() {
        const { id, product, authUser, cart, shippingType } = this.state;

  this.props.firebase.cartItems().doc(authUser.uid).collection('total').doc('total').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            this.props.firebase.cartItems().doc(authUser.uid).collection("total").doc("total").update({'total': snapshot.data().total + (product.salePrice > 0 ? product.salePrice : product.price * 1)
        }).then(() => {

        cogoToast.success("Added to store list");

    });

                console.log("doc info",snapshot.data().total)



        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found an answer to this. so instead of onsnapchat I changed it into get(). here is the new code.

```
this.props.firebase.cartItems().doc(authUser.uid).collection('total').get().then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data());
        this.props.firebase.cartItems().doc(authUser.uid).collection("total").doc("total").update({'total': doc.data().total + (product.salePrice > 0 ? product.salePrice : product.price * 1)})

    });
});
```

Comment: ohh, nice i was also preparing for an answer.. +1